# calculate the expectation in a probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

A power cut is announced in its sector of the city, for which it is decided to charge $4$ batteries for a certain
Electronic device. The times it takes to charge are $5$ hours, $3$ hours, $1$ hour and $1$ hour, and
you want to load them one after the other in that order. Assuming the time it takes to cut the power
is a uniform random variable between $0$ and $12$ hours, calculate the expectation of the number of batteries that
are fully charged.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share with us your ideas, how you applied them and where you got stuck.

Comment: I am unsure whether I am interpreting the question correctly.  If I am not interpreting the question correctly, then this comment **should be ignored**.  I think that you have $5$ mutually exclusive possibilities, depending on whether the random variable is in $[0,5)$, or is in $[5,8)$, or is in $[8,9)$, or is in $[9,10)$, or is in $[10,12]$.  The probability of each possibility occurring should be proportional to the width of the corresponding interval.  For example, the possibility that the random variable is in $[0,5)$ is $\displaystyle \frac{5}{12}$.

Comment: I have never studied Probability/Statistics formally, so my intuition could be leading me astray here.  My understanding is : Suppose that you have $n$ mutually exclusive events $E_1, E_2, \cdots E_n$.  Also suppose that you have a function $f(x)$ that will take on the value $f(k)$ if event $E_k$ occurs $~: ~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.  Similarly, suppose that the probability of event $E_k$ occurring is $p(k)$, where $[p(1) + p(2) + \cdots + p(n)] = 1.$  Then I would surmise (**perhaps wrongly**) that the expected value of $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n \left[p(k) \times f(k)\right].$$

Answer (score 1):

If T = time power is ON, then T has a Uniform distribution [0,12].

If X = number of batteries that get fully charged, then

$ X=0\quad if \quad 0 \leqslant T\lt5, \quad  prob = 5/12 $

$ X=1\quad if \quad 5 \leqslant T\lt8, \quad  prob = 3/12 $

$ X=2 \quad if \quad 8 \leqslant T \lt9, \quad prob = 1/12 $

$ X=3 \quad if \quad 9 \leqslant T \lt10, \quad prob = 1/12 $

$ X=4 \quad if \quad 10 \leqslant T \lt12, \quad prob = 2/12 $

Hence,$ \quad E(X) = 0 + 3/12 + 2/12 + 3/12 + 8/12 \;= \;4/3 $ batteries

Comment: If $T<5$, then $0$ batteries get fully charged.

Comment: Thank you paw88789 for putting me right.